# Change unique id Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, local-storage, winrt-xaml

i'm developing a simple App for study purpose with xaml/c# in windows 8.1
I'm using visual studio 2013.
When i run my app, a package is created in [myUser]/AppData/Local/Packages/[nameGiveByVS2013]

Is possible to modify the name given by VisualStudio?
Is not so friendly to search between nonsense strings like this

> d5842d81-6878-42d6-a6a8-8e2662fa5fee_p7hgv9ttr51fm

or

> be98b3ac-bae7-4d9b-b74a-de13645d56b0_gradkm92q1szg

or there are tricks to add something.

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

It's just an id generate by visual studio. You can change this id easy and see the result [myUser]/AppData/Local/Packages/[nameGiveByVS2013]

Comment: i know that's just an id generate by visual studio, i just wanna know if i can change some parameters in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you link your project with Windows Store by **Project (right-click) -> Store -> Associate with the store...**, the id will be changed similarly to your given name at the store. much friendly than such a random string.